# Adding NSMutableDictionary to NSMutableArray - iOS, Objective - C

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablearray, nsarray, nsdictionary, nsmutabledictionary

In a ViewController (A), I have created a property as below:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *someList;
```

In another ViewController (B), an instance of NSMutableDictionary is added to the someList property but it always gives null. Please help.
In B,

```
A = [[A alloc] init];
[A.someList addObject:someInitializedMutableDictionary];
```

Comment: You have to initialize your `someList` property otherwise it will always remain null

Answer (score 1):

You need to allocate the `someList` property, which is normally done in the `init` method of the subclass. However there is an issue in that the `init` method for view controllers isn't generally implemented in a subclass, and doing that kind of stuff is preferred in `viewDidLoad`.

Therefore I would recommend you create a method to add stuff to `someList`, like this:

```
@implementation A
...

- (void)addToSomeList:(id)object
{
    if (!_someList)
        _someList = [NSMutableArray new];
    [_someList addObject:object];
}
```

and this will allocate `someList` as soon as something needs to be added to it.

Comment: There are KVC method conventions for this …

Comment: @AminNegm-Awad Please elaborate.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Articles/Compliant.html

Comment: @AminNegm-Awad Ah yes; using that would make more sense.

Comment: Yes, esp. because you get benefits as `-mutableArrayValueForKey:@"items"`

Answer (score 0):

Does someList ever get initialized? You can't add to something that doesn't 'exist' yet.

You somewhere have to say:

```
self.someList = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

*self* of course only when you do this inside the ViewController A

Comment: Allocating properties from outside is a poor pattern to promote.

Answer (score 0):

The basic problem of your approach is that a collection property shouldn't be mutable. There are several problem with it. So, first let us change this. Additionally you have to add mutating methods (mutators), instead.

```
@interface MyClass
@property (readonly, nonatomic) NSArray *items;                   // Better naming
-(void)insertObject:(Item*)item inItemsAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index; // See below
@end
```

Doing so there are two "problems":

- How can one change the property?
- Isn't the ivar immutable, too?

**Mutable ivar**

To get a mutable ivar, just declare it in the implementation:

```
@implementation MyClass
{
  NSMutableArray _items;
}
```

This ivar will be used by synthesized properties, because it has the right name and a legal type (subclass of property).

You can initialize that ivar early in the objects life cycle, i. e. `-init`, `-viedDidLoad`, $whatever. Or you can do it lazily in the accessor methods(example in trojanfoe's answer).

Additionally you can have a setter internally, if you add a class continuation in the .m-File switching the property to read/write.

*If* you have a setter, you should explicitly define that having a mutable copy:

```
-(void)setItems:(NSArray*)items // Arg type from property
{
  _items = [items mutableCopy];
}
```

**Changing**

There are several KVC methods you should implement. You can find a list [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Articles/Compliant.html). I. e.:

```
-(void)insertObject:(Item*)item inItemsAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index
{
  [_items insertObject:item atIndex:index];
}
```

Usually it is simply sending one appropriate message to the collection.